# How to connect MS SQL database using React-Native ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, reactjs, react-native

I am building a react native app for mobile on my MacBook. I want to connect MS SQL server where is installed in VMware Fusion virtual machine.
How can ı connect my MS SQL server on my MacBook?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't. Or more appropriately, you shouldn't. React is a front end library and it should connect to a backend service such as REST API which then connects to MS SQL database.

The reason why you shouldn't is simple. Front-end libraries have all their code running in the client's browser which allows the user to view the source. If the user can view the source and there is a database connection in the source, he'll be able to connect directly to your database.

By using a REST API, you can hide all database connection information on your server to which the user has no access.

Sample tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-crud-with-reactjs-and-entity-framework

Comment: Thanks for answer but this site develop for visual studio. I want to build javascript api layer? How can ı do this ?

Comment: For that you would use node.js: https://codeburst.io/build-simple-medium-com-on-node-js-and-react-js-a278c5192f47

Answer (score 5):

A little too late but just in case someone trying to find a way to directly access an MSSQL database from his react-native app like I did.

https://github.com/davidstoneham/react-native-mssql

I still agree with @bobek's answer that it isn't the best approach but handy when you don't want to create an API layer and have direct access to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. Sometimes we just want to test our apps before moving onto API creation. Sometimes it's for a small department to be used by only a few people only on the intranet. Not everything goes into production like that.